# Workaround Way To Install Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, cron, installation

Right now I have a script which uses numpy that I want to run automatically on a server.  When I ssh in and run it manually, it works fine.  However, when I set it to run as a cron job, it can't find numpy.  Apparently due to the shared server environment, the cron demon for whatever reason can't find numpy.  I contacted the server host's tech support and they told me to set up a vps or get my own damn server.  Is there any way to hack a workaround for this?  Perhaps, by moving certain numpy files into the same directory as the script?

Comment: There are hosting providers that pride themselves on Python support, perhaps you should consider switching.

Comment: It's not my call, and the server wasn't originally intended to be used for my purposes in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have numpy installed somewhere on the server, you can add it into the import path for python; at the beginning of your script, do something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/numpy")
import numpy
```

Comment: The other answers were all very useful, but since I can't change the crontab file directly, so I had to go with this one.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The cronjob runs with an empty environment. As such, it's either not using the same python binary as you are at the shell, or you have PYTHONPATH set, which it won't have under crontab.

You should run `env -i HOME=$HOME sh` to get a fascimile of the cronjob's environment. Set environment variables until your command works, and record them.

You can then set these in your crontab file, again using the env command, like:

```
* * * * * env PYTHONPATH=/my/pythonpath OTHERVAR=correct-value /path/to/mycommand
```

Comment: Note, the ability to set environment variables within crontab files depends on the implementation of `cron`.  It will not work on Solaris 10 for example.

Comment: That env -i command was really useful in making sure everything was how it should be, but since the server host only gives me access to crontab files indirectly through their online GUI, I couldn't add any new lines to it.  Thanks a lot though, it really helped.

Comment: You can use the env command to add things to the environment of your command (that's its chief purpose, really), like: `env FOO=bar mycommand`). This should give you full control, even with the gui limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Your cron job is probably executing with a different python interpreter.

Log in as you (via ssh), and say `which python`. That will tell you where your python is. Then have your cron job execute that python interpreter to run your script, or `chmod +x` your script and put the path in a `#!` line at the top of the script.

Comment: @bukzor you are correct, I was thinking of the system crontab rather than a user's crontab. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Processes invoked by the cron daemon have a minimal environment, generally consisting of `$HOME`, `$LOGNAME` and `$SHELL`.

It sounds like numpy is perhaps somewhere on your `$PYTHONPATH`?  If so, you will need to specify that within the crontab line.  Such as

```
/usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=... <then the command to run>
```

If you are on a Linux system using vixie cron, then you can also specify global variables in your crontab by using lines such as

```
# my environment settings
PYTHONPATH = <path>
SOMETHING_ELSE = blah

<then my normal cron line>
```

See `man -s 5 crontab`